# convert timestamp with timezone to readable date

Tags: php

I want to convert timestamp to readable date format, the timestamp is : **/Date(1434434419100-0400)/** but not sure how to deal with it together with the timezone issue.

```
date('Y-m-d H:i:s', substr($editDate, -20, -7))
```

Thanks

Comment: 1434434419100-0400 this which time stamp?

Comment: your timestamp isnot correct.

Comment: first time to encounter this date format, don't know what to call this.. I just assume that this is a timestamp with timezone.

Comment: @Monnster please mark and up-vote the answer for others help. thanks

Answer (score 2):

With timestamp you mean the Unix Epoch time?

When dealing with times and dates I always find something useful at http://www.epochconverter.com.

For PHP, see [Programming > Epoch in PHP](http://www.epochconverter.com/programming/functions-php.php)

Using the `date` function.

```
$epoch = 1340000000;
echo date('r', $epoch); // output as RFC 2822 date - returns local time
echo gmdate('r', $epoch); // returns GMT/UTC time
```

Using the `DateTime` class

```
$epoch = 1344988800; 
$dt = new DateTime("@$epoch");  // convert UNIX timestamp to PHP DateTime
echo $dt->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'); // output = 2012-08-15 00:00:00
```

Setting your timezone

If you are using PHP 5.1 or higher use [date_default_timezone_set](http://php.net/date_default_timezone_set) to set/overrule your timezone.
The PHP time zone handling takes care of daylight saving times ([list of PHP time zones](http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php)).

---

The value you give - `1434434419100-0400` - is definitely not a standard formatted timestamp. See [w3.org](http://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime) and [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) for an overview of what is considered standard. The closest I could find it that it is a epoch time `1434434419` (i.e. Tue, 16 Jun 2015 06:00:19 GMT) plus `100-0400`. No idea what `100` means, but `-0400` could then indicate the [UTC−04:00](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC%E2%88%9204:00).

Comment: the date given to me is 1434434419100-0400, what is 0400 part? is that a timezone? sorry first time to encounter this format.

Comment: I added a section looking at your specific value. Perhaps you find it useful.

Answer (score 0):

First set the timezone by `date_default_timezone_set("Europe/Helsinki");`
Second use `echo date('m/d/Y H:i:s', 1299446702);` where `1299446702` is `time();`

Answer (score 0):

You can convert time stamp to date as follows..

```
$date = new DateTime("@".$timestamp);
```

To deal with timezone, please refer [this](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.gmstrftime.php)